# Google Sheets Script - Cannot read property 1.0?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to enter in data via a script, so that it finds the first empty row, and in that row the first empty column and enter the data into that column. For each  row there will be several columns to insert information into, and it is done in separate requests which I realize is another problem that I have to solve, but I haven't gotten there yet.

```
var answer = e.parameter["value"]
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(e.parameter["sheet"]);
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var column = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, column);
  var data = range.getValues();

  for(var i = 1; i <= column; i++){
    if (data[1][i] == "" || data[1][i] == " "){
      sheet.getRange(1, i).setValue(answer);
      break;
    }
  }
```

I am getting this error when it is run: **"message":"Cannot read property \"1.0\" from undefined.","name":"TypeError","fileName":"Code (Database Macro)","lineNumber":107,"stack":"\tat Code (Database Macro):107 (doPost**

EDITED CODE:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= column; i++){
    if (data[i] == ""){
      sheet.getRange(row, i).setValue(answer);
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: so as I understand @Austin you need first to find a way to "find first empty row", then go to each cells in that row (cols) right?

Comment: @oserek Yup! You got it.

Comment: javascript arrays start at zero, not 1. use the apps script debugger to find the error.

Comment: Which line number is 107, might be useful to add

Comment: you are only adding data in the last row in your code. However, from you question it seems you want to find an empty row? Does that mean the whole row is empty or a row with empty column?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing you sheet where you can see how I find first empty row (cell value) in range A1:A10

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12w3Xi2CsOQ7u0i6gB5T7SWhG5_Kkv_04UJOp2ouNpF0/edit?usp=sharing

```
function myFunction() {
  var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A10").getValues();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ix = null;
  for( var i = 0 ; i < aa.length; i++){
    if( aa[ i ] == "" ) { ix = i; break; }
  }
  ui.alert( "first empty row is: A" + (ix+1) ); 
}
```

hth, cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

Javascript array index starts at 0 not 1  as mentioned by @ZigMandel so modify the below code:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= column; i++){
    if (data[1][i] == "" || data[1][i] == " "){ // This i believe is your line 107
      sheet.getRange(1, i).setValue(answer);
      break;
    }
  }
```

to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < column; i++){
        if (data[0][i] == "" || data[0][i] == " "){
          sheet.getRange(1, i).setValue(answer);
          break;
        }
      }
```

The error you are get is most likely because of this statement data[1][i]. Since array index starts at 0 and you got one row from your this code:

```
 var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, column);
  var data = range.getValues();
```

There is no index 1, hence data[1] is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for that. I did edit my code a little bit to better match what I'm trying to do and I ran into a different problem.

Comment: I edited my original question with my new code. Currently it does not register that data[i] is blank, even though I printed it out to confirm it, and what I get is [["", "", ""]]. So it's blank, but it's not identifying that it's blank.

Comment: Data is 2D array, hence you are getting the above. In a 2D array like data =[[1,2],[3,4]], data[0] = [1,2] which is an another array and hence != "".